# using R, how to just stack bar values without summarizing?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
duration <- c(270,1740,90,30,180,180, 20, 300, 150)
no <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2)
class <- c("7","1","2","1","2","3","1","3","2")

data <- cbind(duration, no, class)
data <- data.frame(data)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=no, y=duration, fill=class)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I want to make a plot that just shows the data values as they are. For example, from the bottom, no1, class 7, duration 270 and then no1, **class 1**, duration 1740 and then no1, class 2, duration 90, and no1, **class 1 again**, duration 30...

However, this bar plot automatically summarizes depending on "class". Or when I tried to set levels..still the order is messed up and

```
data$Legend1 <- factor(data$Legend1, level=c("7","1","2","1","2","3"))
```

got a warning. Absolutely it wasn't a good way to solve this problem since levels are different between all "no".

```
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :   duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

This is my bar plot after level set:

[image]

Since I'm a newbie, my question can be more of basic, I'm troubling with this matter for a week though. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some points to note:

Issue 1. `duration` in your dataset is a factor, not a number. You can skip `cbind()` & create your data frame directly from the vectors to avoid that:

```
duration <- c(270,1740,90,30,180,180, 20, 300, 150)
no <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2)
class <- c("7","1","2","1","2","3","1","3","2")

data <- data.frame(duration, no, class)

> str(data)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ duration: num  270 1740 90 30 180 180 20 300 150
 $ no      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
 $ class   : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","7": 4 1 2 1 2 3 1 3 2
```

Issue 2. The stacked bars are automatically grouped according to the fill colours. You can avoid that by specifying the group by row number:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data %>% group_by(no) %>% mutate(rowid = rev(row_number())), 
       aes(x=no, y=duration, group = rowid, fill=class)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

(Side note: you can use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat="identity")` too.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want!! Following your answer, by the way, I got the reversed(;;) graph. Is there any procedure that I have to do first? I don't understand why the value order is different.

Comment: @elsie Sorry, there should have been a `rev()` on the row_number(). I was three quarters done with my answer before I realized that you want the first row in the data frame at the bottom. The chart was generated after that, but I'd already pasted in the solution code & forgot to change that. Have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

just leave the **cbind** out of your code. You don't need that.

```
library(ggplot2)
duration <- c(270,1740,90,30,180,180, 20, 300, 150)
no <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2)
class <- c("7","1","2","1","2","3","1","3","2")

data <- data.frame(duration, no, class)

ggplot(data, aes(x=no, y=duration, fill=class)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

should do what you want it to do!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but following code above allows me to get the wrong plot. I didn't get the plot like you attached. each value added up depending on class thus, only 4 types of class are shown.

Comment: @elsie you shure. could you just attach the plot you get after running the code above